# How to get that check box is enable or disable status using Selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, testng

**html code :**

```
input type="checkbox" class="checkbox_one" disabled
```

if checkbox is not disable text is not coming.

```
Assert.assertTrue(webelemt.getAttribute("innerHTML").contains("disabled"));
```

Comment: Show us what is `webelemt` and which locator you've defined  ?

Comment: @cruisepandey - I am using xpath [//span[@title='fieldItem']//preceding-sibling::input]

Comment: See below for illustration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `.getAttribute` method to have a condition where it will check for it's content and if that is not empty, assert should be pass, if empty assert should be fail.

**Code :**

```
    WebElement webelemt = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@title='fieldItem']//preceding-sibling::input"));
    String checkBoxStatus = "";
    if (!webelemt.getAttribute("disabled").isEmpty() && webelemt.getAttribute("disabled").contains("disabled")) {
        System.out.println("Disabled must be present");
        checkBoxStatus = "disabled";
        Assert.assertTrue(true);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Should not it be enabled  ?  or do we need if-else to handle that part as well.");
        Assert.assertTrue(false);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use....

```
ele = driver.find_element_by_class_name('checkbox_one')

if ele.is_selected():
    // do something
else:
    // do something
```